# How to send dynamically added row values from angular to java controller

Tags: json, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I created a dynamically adding/deleting rows using Angular reactive forms. Rows are getting added and deleted. But how you can send all these row values from Angular application to java controller.I am pasting the code below.

[image]

app.component.html

```
<div class="container">
<h3 class="page-header">Seasons</h3>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addTeam()">Add New Row</button><br/>
<form [formGroup] = "seasonsForm">
    <div formArrayName = "teamRows">
        <div *ngFor = "let team of seasonsForm.controls.teamRows.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName] = "i">
            <h4>Team- #{{i+1}}</h4>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Team Name</label>
                <input formControlName = "teamName" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Stadium</label>
                <input formControlName = "stadiumName" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Capacity</label>
                <input formControlName = "capacity" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Founded</label>
                <input formControlName = "founded" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Head Coach</label>
                <input formControlName = "headCoach" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Last Season</label>
                <input formControlName = "lastSeason" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <button *ngIf = "seasonsForm.controls.teamRows.controls.length" (click) = "deleteTeam(i)" class="btn btn-danger">Delete Button</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<pre>{{ seasonsForm.value |json }}</pre>
</div>
```

app.component.ts

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormGroup,FormArray,FormBuilder,Validators} from '@angular/forms';
    import { Teams } from '../service/http-client.service';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

      public seasonsForm: FormGroup;
      public teams:Teams[];

      constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) { }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.seasonsForm = this._fb.group({
          teamRows: this._fb.array([this.initTeamRows()])
        });
      }

      get formArr() {
        return this.seasonsForm.get('teamRows') as FormArray;
      }

      initTeamRows() {
        return this._fb.group({
          teamName: [''],
          stadiumName: [''],
          capacity: [''],
          founded: [''],
          headCoach: [''],
          lastSeason: ['']
        });
      }

      addTeam() {
        this.formArr.push(this.initTeamRows());
      }

      deleteTeam(index: number) {
        this.formArr.removeAt(index);
      }

    }

createTeam(): void {
    this.httpClient.post<Teams>("http://localhost:8080/addTeam", seasonsForm);
      .subscribe( res => {
        alert("Successful");
      })
  };


export class Teams {
  constructor(
    public teamName:string,
    public stadiumName:string,
    public capacity:string,
    public founded:string,
    public headCoach:string,
    public lastSeason:string,
  ) {}

}
```

I tried to send entire formGroup(seasonsForm) but it is getting failed.I am relatively new to Angular and i searched in Google but i didn't find much help. So any help in this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all if you are using NoSQL database then you can send a JSON file containing arrays. So here i decided to send a json file containing Array values to server side and then i converted the form group name to JSON.Stringify. In Server side you can retrieve that json in String format and parse it and send to DB. Here is the code below

```
onSubmit() {
    this.httpClient.post("http://localhost:8080/addTeams",JSON.stringify(this.seasonsForm.value))
  .subscribe((response: Response) => {

  })

    alert("Successful");
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to send form value on your createTeam function. If you console.log(seasonsForm), you can see there are some other attributes which is only about your form. 
Also if you want you can check is form valid.

```
createTeam(): void {
    if(seasonsForm.valid){
        this.httpClient.post<Teams>("http://localhost:8080/addTeam", seasonsForm.value);
          .subscribe( res => {
            alert("Successful");
          })
      };
}
```